# MacOS viewWillAppear at Storyboard Segue

Tags: macos

I am using MacOS. I have two different views, each with an own viewcontroller.
In the 1st view there is a textfield connected to global variable "test".
There is button connected with a segue to my 2nd view (I dont know if kind "show, modal, sheet, popover or custom" make any difference.)

When I change the value of "test" in my 2nd view the 1st view can work with the changed value - but when I just close the 2nd view the textfield doesnt get updated.

I tried to update "test" in "viewWillAppear".
If I hide the project and bring it back "test" gets updated. But I want to have it instantly updated.
May anyone help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`NSViewcontroller` has a property `presenting` (Swift) / `presentingViewController` (Objective-C). As the name implies this is a reference to the presenting view controller which gives you access to the `test` property.

Comment: May you give me an example line of code please (for Swift)?
I tried it but dont get any code with presenting and similar working. ( I am a real newbie)

Comment: Thank you very much vadian!!
The 2nd link was exactly what I needed.